# C++ CppUnitTest changes DLL-Layout

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, dllexport

I'm working on a C++ application with a vast amount of DLLs. Now I am trying to Unit test them with the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Test Framework. I need to unit test the internal logic, as the DLL is rather big and only the most necessary functions are exported. So i followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls?view=vs-2019#sameProject and executing the tests works pretty fine but when starting the application for the next time, I figured out that the DLL did not get loaded anymore. The reason was that the DLL-Layout has been modified by the Unit Test.
Before adding the test:

[image]

After adding the test:

[image]

It's pretty clear why these methods appear, but is there

- any possibility to move them to the bottom end of the dll?
- any other possibility to add tests to a DLL that are able to test not exported functions without converting the .dll into a .lib?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would the order of exported symbols in the DLL cause you problems when using the DLL? Have you somehow hardcoded the expected ordinals? Or was the application simply built with an out-of-date import library?

Comment: To be honest, I am not completely sure, but I don't expect expect it to be hardcoded:
 - In the application I do have a MyLibAPI.h which defines the three imported methods as

`extern "C"
{
    MyLibDeclImport bool method1();
    MyLibDeclImport bool method2();
    MyLibDeclImport Object * method3();
}`

That  is what I thought would be the counterpart. And I did build the application after building the dll.
Thank you for trying to help me - do you have any further suggestions for files I can look into?

Comment: It sounds like that's the problem you need to solve.

Comment: I suspect you're using an out-of-date import library (as opposed to an out-of-date DLL). But "did not get loaded anymore" is not a specific error. If you search by the actual symptoms/error, you're likely to find more directly applicable suggestions for how to troubleshoot.